# Using R aggregate() function, how do I count distinct values?

Tags: r

My data look like this:

```
str(defects)

## 'data.frame':    22540 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ BUG_ID         : int  2237 2239 2163 2163 2163 2163 2163 2163 2163 2163 ...
##  $ STATUS         : Factor w/ 5 levels "Assigned","Closed",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
##  $ SEVERITY       : Factor w/ 4 levels "1-Low","2-Medium",..: 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
##  $ DETECTION_DATE : Date, format: "2017-10-31" "2017-10-31" ...
##  $ ACTUAL_FIX_TIME: int  1 1 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
##  $ CLOSING_DATE   : Date, format: "2017-10-31" "2017-10-31" ...
##  $ DATE           : Date, format: "2017-10-31" "2017-10-31" ...
##  $ NOR            : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

**I need to calculate the following using the aggregate function:**

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(
    IF [CLOSING_DATE] == [DATE] THEN
        [BUG_ID] 
    END  
)
```

Here is what I have:

```
aggregate(unique(BUG_ID) ~ DATE, defects, subset = CLOSING_DATE == DATE, length)
```

Comment: Do you have to use `aggregate`? You should be able to get the count/length of the values directly - e.g.: `length(unique(defects$BUG_ID[defects$CLOSING_DATE == defects$DATE]))`

Comment: The aggregate will be used for a time series. So, I need a vector with a distinct count for each date, @thelatemail

Comment: Right - that makes sense. I think you still need to do the `unique` separately. E.g. - `aggregate(BUG_ID ~ DATE, data = unique(defects[defects$CLOSING_DATE == defects$DATE,]), length)`

Comment: @thelatemail, your code kind of does it but it excludes like 4 rows. I am supposed to have 303 rows but I get 209.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but try adding `na.action = na.pass` as an argument - `aggregate`'s formula interface drops `NA` rows.

Comment: still 209 @thelatemail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219113/discussion-between-ramin-melikov-and-thelatemail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
aggregate(CLOSED_DEFECTS ~ DATE, data = within(defects, CLOSED_DEFECTS <- ifelse(CLOSING_DATE == DATE, BUG_ID, NA)), function (x) if(length(x) > 0) length(unique(x)) - 1 else 0, na.action = na.pass)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer now. I am supposed to count distinct.